# Insert spaces into a string at each change of character

Tags: php, regex, recursion, split, preg-replace

I'm trying to create a string with a blank space between all "different characters, for example:

```
"11131221133112" should result in "111 3 1 22 11 33 11 2"
"1321131112" should result in "1 3 2 11 3 111 2"
```

I tried the following recursive function, not knowing if this is the best way because I couldn't find any build-in function in PHP for this.

```
function stringSplitter($str) {
    $strArr = str_split($str);

    foreach ($strArr as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == count($strArr)-1) return (substr($str, 0));

        if ($value != $strArr[$key+1]) {
            return (substr($str, 0, $key+1)." ".stringSplitter(substr($str, $key)));
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, this function seems to iterate infinitely, and I can't figure out why. Where do I go wrong?

Is there a better way to do this? I want to use explode to out the answering string in an array, can this be done directly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**RegEx** approach, 
In RegEx **\1** it's a backreference for what has been captured by **\d**

```
 <?php 
    $pattern    = '/(\d)\1*/';
    $str        = '11131221133112';

    $r = preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $result);
    if ($r !== FALSE) {
        var_dump(implode(' ', $result[0]));
    }
    else {
        print 'error';  
    }
```

Comment: I haven't touched PHP in about 4 years but shouldn't it be `!=` rather than `!==` in the *if* condition?

Comment: `-1` not enough jQuery... but more seriously, +1 for showing a rare 1/100 case when a RegEx **is** useful indeed without being code smell... (although I still like [regex-less solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34199965/719662) more *chuckle*)

Comment: @displayName **===** used to compare variable type and his value, for example, this test will return **true**  `0 == FALSE` ...

Answer (score 5):

simplest solution is:

```
$string = '11131221133112';
$strarr = str_split($string);
$tmp = null;
$newstr = '';
foreach($strarr as $a){
    $newstr .= ($a == $tmp) ? $a:' '.$a;
    $tmp = $a;
}

echo $newstr;
```

output: `111 3 1 22 11 33 11 2`

Answer (score 2):

Nice question :)

You can loop over your characters and keep an eye on the last one, if it is different from the current character add a space to output, then add the character itself.

```
<?php
$string="11131221133112";
$last="";

for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++)
{
   $output.= $string[$i]!=$last ? " ".$string[$i] :  $string[$i];
   $last=$string[$i];
}
$output=trim($output);
```

**Output**

```
111 3 1 22 11 33 11 2
```

And

```
1 3 2 11 3 111 2
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/483268)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$string="11131221133112";
$seperated=str_split($string);
$lastChar='';
foreach ($seperated as $key => $value) {
    if($lastChar!=''&&$lastChar!=$value){
            echo ' ';
    }
    $lastChar=$value;
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: "Try this": What happens if I try? Will it succeed or fail?

Answer (score 0):

"*I'm trying to create a string with a blank space between all "different characters*" ...okay, then you don't need to split the string into an array at all.  Just insert a space between each differing character.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/giArN))

```
$str = '11131221133112';

var_export(
    preg_replace(
        '/(\d)\1*\K(?!$)/',
        ' ',
        $str
    )
);
// '111 3 1 22 11 33 11 2'
```

My output shows the string wrapped in single quotes because `var_export()` is used to demonstrate that there are no leading or trailing spaces created.

Pattern breakdown:

```
(\d)    #capture the first digit
\1*     #match zero or more copies of the first digit
\K      #forget previously matched characters
(?!$)   #not followed by the end of the string
```